# What does `forEach((c) => c())` mean in Dart?

Tags: arrays, dart, closures

I can't understand last line of this code.
`callbacks.add(() => print(i));` seems to be obvious for me: add anonymous function which prints `i` to array .

But `.forEach((c) => c());` I can't understand.
`=>` separates header of functions from body as I understand, so it looks like function declaration for me. But then it looks like declare this function for each - but that's nonsense.

```
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  callbacks.add(() => print(i));
}
callbacks.forEach((c) => c());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(c) => c()` defines an anonymous function with an untyped parameter, `c`. The function, invoked for each item in the list, executes callback function referenced by `c`. Also, `(c) => c()` function contains only one statement `c()` in its body, therefore, it shortened using `=>` - fat arrow notation. Otherwise, it could be written as `(c) { c(); }`.

See [anonymous functions](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions) for details

Answer (score 2):

Understand from a simple example:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var listOfCallbacks = [
   () => stdout.write('h'),//printt will add new line stdout.write() will not do that
   () => stdout.write('e'),
   () => stdout.write('l'),
   () => stdout.write('l'),
   () => stdout.write('o'),
  ];

  listOfCallbacks.forEach((c) => c()); //hello
}
```

`List` contains a list of functions(callbacks) using `forEach`, iterate through each and every callbacks(elements).

Answer (score 1):

If `callbacks` is an array of callback functions

You have something like this:

```
callbacks = [a, b, c, d, e];
```

Calling `callbacks.forEach()`means do something on "each" elements in callbacks.

The function `.forEach()` calls a function "for each value" in the array:

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});

// expected output: "a"
// expected output: "b"
// expected output: "c"
```

Copied from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

However, in your case, each element is a function itself, and you are giving each one the alias `c` instead of `element`.

```
callbacks.forEach((c) => c());
```

This can also be written as:

```
// Where c is each element
callbacks.forEach( function(c) { 

    // Call c, which is the ith element
    // in the array 'callbacks'
    c();
});
```

But, since you have an array of "callable" functions, you are executing each callback in the array of callback functions, hence - `c();`

So you are looping through an array of functions and executing each one. It's syntactic sugar for:

```
// Array of functions
let callbacks = [a, b, c, d, e];

// Loop through array
for (let i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {

    let f = callbacks[i];

    // Call each function
    f();
}
```