# disentangling (c) => c()

Tags: dart, anonymous-function

I have an issue with : (c) => c() which I found [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227165/what-does-foreachc-c-mean-in-dart).
I understand that it defines an anonymous function with an untyped parameter, c. But then it seems to refer

- to a parameter-free undefined function c(), i.e. having the same name as the parameter of the initial-anonymous function,
- or to its own parameter c as if this very parameter were a parameter-free undefined function it-self.

I'm pretty sure that I did not get it right and that I miss the point, but any hint would help to untangle (c) and c(), and grasp what the function ends up doing for real.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anonymous function that gets something named `c`. It then *calls* what it gets as if it were a function. That implies that the compiler figured out that it either *is* a function with no parameters, or it is a `dynamic`. Otherwise the compiler would have complained.

So in english: an anonymous function that has a parameter named `c`. The type of that parameter is "function with no parameters". It then *calls* the function it just got as argument.

Comment: Many thanks for the feed back, and apologies for the questions are likely to look naive to non-beginner. 

If the anonymous function then calls the function it just got as argument, could we write it, at least conceptually, "(c()) => c()" to emphasize that the argument and the internal function refers to the same entity ?

Comment: They do refer to the same entity. The `()` are just the call, `c` is the name. The same way `print` refers to the print function and the `()` are only needed to call it.